# MySQL Group by SUM

Tags: mysql, sql

I have category in a table like

**table**(cat_name,amount);

How to get the sum of `amount` each `cat_name` Grouped by `cat_name`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
SELECT cat_name, SUM(amount) AS total_amount
FROM table
GROUP BY cat_name
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT cat_name, SUM(amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM Table
GROUP BY cat_name
```