# Complex MySQL Sum from same table

Tags: mysql

My table name is HaveGoal.
I have a table that contains columns:id,week,goals
I want a query that sums all goals with the same id and will give me number and its total goals in table

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: And even before you ask a good question: Search for other questions and answers to them. You might have found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105767/mysql-group-by-sum

Comment: Just a side remark: A column named ID in a table should be the table's unique ID. So "all goals with the same id" would be nonsense. Maybe you just made up a bad example, otherwise you should think over your data model.

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total goals:

```
SELECT id, SUM(goals), COUNT(goals)
FROM HaveGoal
GROUP BY id
```

Total goals per week:

```
SELECT id, week, SUM(goals), COUNT(goals)
FROM HaveGoal
GROUP BY id, week
```