# SQL transactions sum for each year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a tranaction date and a transaction price. Like so:

- 12/01/08    $1500
- 20/05/08    $1200
- 09/08/15    $2000
- 12/09/15    $3000

I want to be able to find the sum of transactions for each year. How do I add them together. I only know how to add example + example as "example".

Select transaction_id, transaction_date, transaction_amount
from transactions_table

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to find your answer, in two parts, in the following questions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6105767/3004881 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/508791/3004881

Answer (score 0):

You'll need something like:

```
SELECT SUM(transaction_amount), transaction_date
FROM transaction_table
GROUP BY YEAR(Transaction_date)
```

This will sum up all transactions and group them by year.

Comment: This groups them by date, not by year.