# Adding certain rows together with respect to another column - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Suppose I had a table that looked like:

```
|   C1   | C2  | C3 | C4  |
|  AAAA  | 11  | 14 | 12  |
|  AAAA  | 21  | 04 | 31  |
|  AAAA  | 17  | 24 | 13  |
|  AAAA  | 13  | 13 | 14  |
|  AAAA  | 11  | 23 | 12  |
|  AAAA  | 19  | 21 | 15  |
|  BBBB  | 11  | 11 | 19  |
|  BBBB  | 16  | 11 | 18  |
|  BBBB  | 17  | 14 | 13  |
|  BBBB  | 13  | 12 | 13  |
|  BBBB  | 12  | 21 | 11  |
|  BBBB  | 12  | 21 | 13  |
```

This is what I want it to look like:

```
|   C1  | C2  | C3 | C4  |
|  AAAA | 92  | 99 | 97  |
|  BBBB | 81  | 90 | 87  |
```

I know I can do something like:

```
SELECT SUM( C2 ), SUM( C3 ), SUM( C4 ) 
FROM mytable;
```

The problem is that it takes the entire sum of the entire column. Is there a way so that it will do it with respect to the content in C1?

Comment: You are looking for `group by c1`

Comment: As in: SELECT SUM( C2 ), SUM( C3 ), SUM( C4 ) FROM mytable GROUP BY C1; ?

Comment: As in: SELECT C1, SUM( C2 ), SUM( C3 ), SUM( C4 ) FROM mytable GROUP BY C1;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Group by SUM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105767/mysql-group-by-sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a group by.

```
SELECT C1, SUM(C2), SUM(C3), SUM(C4) 
FROM mytable GROUP BY C1
```

When a group by is not specified , it will sum the entire table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to group your query
like this

```
SELECT SUM( C2 ), SUM( C3 ), SUM( C4 ) 
FROM mytable GROUP BY C1
```