# how create a ' one to many ' sql query statement

Tags: mysql, sqlite

i have a table called(center_info) which which has a student's information and their total bills paid and total balance remained. and another table called (center_payments) which has records of each single date of bill paid by a student.
I want to join records of a student in table 1(center_info), to every date he paid a bill in table 2(center_payments)

below are the records in center_info:

```
id | student | term | bill | total_paid | total_balance | last_date_of_pymt |
---+---------+------+------+------------+---------------+-------------------+
 5    mary      1     400        200         -200            6 / june / 2019
 6    john      1     500        300         -200            2 / june / 2019
 7    grace     2     450        400         -50          17 / august / 2019
 8    mike      2     450        100         -350         15 / august / 2019
```

and the below are the different dates of payments in center_payments:

```
id | student | paid | balance |     date     | term |
---+---------+------+---------+--------------+------+
5     mary     100     -300    3 / june /2019    1
5     mary     100     -200    6 / june /2019    1
6     john     150     -350    1 / june /2019    1
6     john     150     -200    2 / june /2019    1 
7     grace    400     -50     17 / aug /2019    2
8     mike     50      -400    5 / aug /2019     2
8     mike     50      -350    5 / aug /2019     2
```

I want to join records of students in table 1 and all their individual payments in table 2 where term(column)=1

currently am only able to print out a selected student and view all his records from the two tables with this code :

```
int row = c_FirstTerm.getSelectedRow();
            try{
            String table_click=(c_FirstTerm.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).toString());    
            String sgl="select center_info.id,center_info.student,center_info.bill,center_info.Term,center_info.total_paid,center_info.total_balance,center_info.last_date_of_pymt,center_payments.paid,center_payments.balance,center_payments.date from center_info INNER JOIN center_payments on center_info.term=center_payments.term and center_info.id=center_payments.id and center_info.Student='"+table_click+"'";
        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
```

but assuming I don't select a particular student, how do I create a one-to-many relationship for students and their individual payments from both tables where term=1. eg like this:

```
//first group
id | student | paid | balance |     date     | term |
---+---------+------+---------+--------------+------+
5     mary     100     -300    3 / june /2019    1
5     mary     100     -200    6 / june /2019    1

id | student | term | bill | total_paid | total_balance | last_date_of_pymt |
---+---------+------+------+------------+---------------+-------------------+
 5    mary      1     400        200         -200            6 / june / 2019
_____________________________________________________________________________

//next group
id | student | paid | balance |     date     | term |
---+---------+------+---------+--------------+------+
6     john     150     -350    1 / june /2019    1
6     john     150     -200    2 / june /2019    1

id | student | term | bill | total_paid | total_balance | last_date_of_pymt |
---+---------+------+------+------------+---------------+-------------------+
 6    john      1     500        300         -200            2 / june / 2019
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you need, are you having problem creating the sql to group them?, are you having issues with how to structure the report?, what does *link records of students* mean, do you want it to be "clickable"?.

Comment: @ Petter Friberg, I want an sql query to group records which have similar id and share the same column value(term=1). please that's what I meant by linking the records of students bro

Comment: I think you should rewrite the question, if you need to understand the sql to execute focus only on that.. show tables, some sample data and desired output. Currently you have too much stuff in this question (leave all the jasper reports stuff out).

Comment: ok bro. and I will appreciate it if you can write the sql query for me please

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/q/6105767/5292302, it seems like a straight forward sum, max, group by query.

Comment: thank you @Petter Friberg. but what I want is a one to many relationship sql query.

Comment: still it's same thing, start to select all the fields you like (with the join query and where), then check what to group on (id), then sum (paid) and max(date) the fields as you need.

Comment: I wrote this ``` select a.id,a.student,a.bill,a.term,a.total_paid,a.total_balance,
 a.last_date_of_pymt,b.paid,b.balance,b.date
from center_info a INNER JOIN center_payments b using(id) group by a.id having a.term='1'``` but it doesn't seem to work @Petter Friberg. kindly help

Comment: Does not work?, error executing it??, then I don't see any sum or max in your query...

Comment: @Petter Friberg, for now I just want to join the records from the two tables with similar ids where term=1. am just frustrated already!

Comment: remove the group by, remove having use where instead and check if you get the records you need.

Comment: ```  select a.id,a.student,a.bill,a.term,a.total_paid,a.total_balance,
 a.last_date_of_pymt,b.paid,b.balance,b.date
from center_info a INNER JOIN center_payments b using(id)  where a.term='1'```   this is even worse.it displays all records from the second table and attaches it to the first table. hmmm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195284/discussion-between-petter-friberg-and-rodney-nart).