# Assign rank automatically with its total score

Tags: mysql

I have managed my db in MySQL. My table looks like this:
[image: Design of table]. 
There are a total of 6 types of ratings for each hospital. Each rating has max score of 10. Users vote each rating total of 10. I want to know how do I structure my query that it should automatically calculates rank of each hospital according to its total of rating values. Suppose hospital A has total (180) & hospital B has total (120) then hospital A given auto ranking as 1 & hospital B as 2. Since I have limited knowledge on sql I am not able to structure proper query.

Types of ratings are (charges, behaviour, admission, properInformation, hygine,  treatment)

Comment: need more explanations. and to which field total rating must be calculated. what are all the 6 rating types how to calculate the rating ? etc

Comment: @VigneswaranS updated my post with types of ratings..

Comment: That looks more like a spreadsheet than a table. Perhaps there's scope for normalisation here?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a combination of GROUP BY and SUM.

Here are two good resources to help you with your problem.

[MYSQL SUM GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598700/mysql-sum-group-by)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html